# Change keyboard input method to unicode?

Tags: python

I am going to create an application called 'khmer keyboard input method'
the khmer just come in unicode standard (Range: 1780–17FF).

reference http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U1780.pdf

this application it will allow cambodian to switch from English to Khmer by press
the definded shortcut key (F10 for example).
the application I will improve GUI.

for example

```
if keypress is 'k':
    return unicode(u'\u1780')#KHMER LETTER KA
if keypress is shift+k or is 'K':
   return unicode(u'\u1782')#KHMER LETTER KO

 #.....................

 if keypress is 'F10':
      switch_to_english_keyboard
```

thank for S.Mark that told me

> Hooking keys and sendkeys is different
>   way for Windows and Linux, so you have
>   to do it seperately. In Windows, you
>   can use combination of PyHook and
>   SendKeys

For Linux,I have done to this

Anybody here Know to do this in python(tips,sample,..)
  (Just for WINDOWS )?
    it will be great if there are a simple code or any open source that make it more easy.

***ABOUT KHMER KEYBOARD LAYOUT 
             http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_layout#Khmer

Comment: I hope for your sake there is a way to do this, but I think input encoding is under control of the operating system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no single way. Each IME has its own way of picking a different engine/method.

Comment: what is IME Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams?

Comment: if depend on IME so it will be complicated to do this?if so I use Ms word to input,or notepad.