# Automatically change keyboard layout in WinXP

Tags: python

i want to change keyboard language from english to arabic in python on windows XP, like i have two line edit , write on first one in english and when move to second line edit language will be arabic automatically ??

Comment: You need to be more specific, keyboard layout switching is different for each operating system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are describing a non trivial task. There is - afaik - no standard python package/module to support  multi-language keyboard-layouts for various operating systems. It depends on your OS and the used IME ([Input Method Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090886/change-keyboard-input-method-to-unicode)). Under linux you might use the ibus-bindings or use a system-tool to change the layout. Under windows (which im not familar with) you might consider this post [Win32 Api access to keyboardlayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6725041/python-win32api-loadkeyboardlayout-doesnt-change-language-in-idle-shell) which uses a win32-api call to change the keyboard layot.

I updated my answer, by copying the relevant section from the comment of the OP, just to help users with a similar question:

```
win32api.LoadKeyboardLayout('00000409',1) # to switch to english
win32api.LoadKeyboardLayout('00000401',1) # to switch to arabic
```

Comment: win32api.LoadKeyboardLayout('00000409',1) # to switch to english                                
win32api.LoadKeyboardLayout('00000401',1) # to switch to arabic 
thanks alot []

Comment: @s.jor.ibra Go ahead and add an answer to your question it will stand out more and be useful to others.

Comment: @s.jor.ibra This answer looks helpful. What about accepting it?

Answer (score 3):

```
win32api.LoadKeyboardLayout('00000409',1) # to switch to english

win32api.LoadKeyboardLayout('00000401',1) # to switch to arabic
```