# represent string as if it was written in different keyboard layouts

Tags: python-2.7, replace, keyboard

i was trying to represent input string as he was written in different keyboard layouts
for example:
Input: kak sme
Output: kak sme, ньн сме, ,ньн япе, как сме, как сме

and everything is ok when input is in latin but when it is in cyrillic the output is same as input

my code

```
def mreplace(s, chararray, newchararray):
slist=list(s)
dlist=list(chararray)
rlist=list(newchararray)

for x in range(0, len(slist)):
    charitem=slist[x]
    if charitem in dlist:
        index=dlist.index(charitem)
        try:
            slist[x]=rlist[index]
        except ValueError:
            pass

return ''.join(slist)


def RetJ(input):
a = []
temp_arr = []

keymap = [];
#US
keymap.append(["q","w","e","r","t","y","u","i","o","p","[","]","a","s","d","f","g","h","j","k","l",";","\"","\\","z","x","c","v","b","n","m",",",".","/"])
#BG
keymap.append([",","у","е","и","ш","щ","к","с","д","з","ц",";","ь","я","а","о","ж","г","т","н","в","м","ч","„","ю","й","ъ","э","ф","х","п","р","л","б"])
#BG Phonetic
keymap.append(["ч","ш","е","р","т","ъ","у","и","о","п","я","щ","а","с","д","ф","г","х","й","к","л",";","\"","ь","з","ж","ц","в","б","н","м",",",".","/"])
#BG Tradic Phonetic
keymap.append(["я","в","е","р","т","ъ","у","и","о","п","ш","щ","а","с","д","ф","г","х","й","к","л",";","\"","ю","з","ь","ц","ж","б","н","м",",",".","/"])
#BG Typewriter
keymap.append([",","у","е","и","ш","щ","к","с","д","з","ц",";","ь","я","а","о","ж","г","т","н","в","м","ч","(","ю","й","ъ","э","ф","х","п","р","л","б"])


temp = ''

for map1 in keymap:
    for map2 in keymap:
        temp = mreplace(input,map1,map2)
        if temp not in temp_arr:
            temp_arr.append(temp)
            a.append({"value":"2", "n":temp, "p":"ppp"})

#a = [{"o1":'1'},{"o2":'2'},{"o3":'3'},{"o4":'4'}]
return a;
```

Comment: Very interesting concept; favorited the question! However, there's a problem with the question. It isn't a question. Try to be more specific in describing what you're trying to achieve (i.e. not just "it's effed up in cyrillic") and we'll be more apt to reply.

Comment: hi, my english is very bad and for me is difficult to describe exactly the problem.
the concept is if you are on wrong keyboard layout and try to search something then search is not for what you typed but for every keyboard variant you use

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8734097/automatically-change-keyboard-layout-in-winxp does this look helpful to you?

Answer (score 0):

Hi i finally find a way to work
here is code

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

    import string
    import array

    def mreplace(s, chararray, newchararray):
        if type(s) == type(u''):
            slist = s
        else:
            slist = unicode(s, "utf-8")
        dlist=list(chararray)
        rlist=list(newchararray)
        new_s = ''

        for x in range(0, len(slist)):
            i = 0
            is_replace = False;
            for och in dlist:
                if slist[x] == unicode(och, "utf-8"):
                    new_s = new_s + rlist[i]
                    is_replace = True;
                i = i + 1
            if is_replace == False:
                new_s = new_s + slist[x].encode("utf-8")

        return unicode(new_s, "utf-8")

    def rj(input):
        a = []

        keymap = [];
        #US
        keymap.append(["q","w","e","r","t","y","u","i","o","p","[","]","a","s","d","f","g","h","j","k","l",";","\"","\\","z","x","c","v","b","n","m",",",".","/"])
        #BG
        keymap.append([",","у","е","и","ш","щ","к","с","д","з","ц",";","ь","я","а","о","ж","г","т","н","в","м","ч","„","ю","й","ъ","э","ф","х","п","р","л","б"])
        #BG Phonetic
        keymap.append(["ч","ш","е","р","т","ъ","у","и","о","п","я","щ","а","с","д","ф","г","х","й","к","л",";","\"","ь","з","ж","ц","в","б","н","м",",",".","/"])
        #BG Tradic Phonetic
        keymap.append(["я","в","е","р","т","ъ","у","и","о","п","ш","щ","а","с","д","ф","г","х","й","к","л",";","\"","ю","з","ь","ц","ж","б","н","м",",",".","/"])
        #BG Typewriter
        keymap.append([",","у","е","и","ш","щ","к","с","д","з","ц",";","ь","я","а","о","ж","г","т","н","в","м","ч","(","ю","й","ъ","э","ф","х","п","р","л","б"])

        for map1 in keymap:
            for map2 in keymap:
                temp = mreplace(input,map1,map2)
                if temp not in a:
                    a.append(temp)
        return a

    input = u'гс пщ хьпе ся хсндвьс ьха счп оидп фквжьись'
    output = rj(input)
    print(output)
```

that way if we want to write

```
hi my name is
```

but we are in Bulgarian keyboard layout the we write

```
гс пщ хьпе ся
```

when we call rj with

```
гс пщ хьпе ся
```

then one of the output will

```
hi my name is
```

thats pretty nice if we try to correcting user input

for every one who need a php version 
Here

```
    function keymap($str)
    {
        $keymap = array();
        //US
        $keymap[] = array('q','w','e','r','t','y','u','i','o','p','[',']','a','s','d','f','g','h','j','k','l',';','\'','\\','z','x','c','v','b','n','m',',','.','/');
        //BG
        $keymap[] = array(',','у','е','и','ш','щ','к','с','д','з','ц',';','ь','я','а','о','ж','г','т','н','в','м','ч','„','ю','й','ъ','э','ф','х','п','р','л','б');
        //BG Phonetic
        $keymap[] = array('ч','ш','е','р','т','ъ','у','и','о','п','я','щ','а','с','д','ф','г','х','й','к','л',';','\'','ь','з','ж','ц','в','б','н','м',',','.','/');
        //BG Tradic Phonetic
        $keymap[] = array('я','в','е','р','т','ъ','у','и','о','п','ш','щ','а','с','д','ф','г','х','й','к','л',';','\'','ю','з','ь','ц','ж','б','н','м',',','.','/');
        //BG Typewriter
        $keymap[] = array(',','у','е','и','ш','щ','к','с','д','з','ц',';','ь','я','а','о','ж','г','т','н','в','м','ч','(','ю','й','ъ','э','ф','х','п','р','л','б');

        $out = array();
        $temp = '';

        foreach($keymap as $map1)
        {
            foreach($keymap as $map2)
            {
                $temp = str_replace($map1, $map2, $str);

                if (!in_array($temp, $out))
                {
                    $out[] = $temp;
                }
            }
        }

        return $out;
    }

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r(keymap('гс пщ хьпе ся хсндвьс'));
    echo "</pre>";
```